# whats the includes method in Elixir(Ecto)?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

We using includes or other like joins method(or SQL) in Rails;
 so whats the function solve this problem in Elixir(Ecto)?

Answer (score 7):

In Ecto you have the `preload` function. There are two ways to use a preload [Ecto.Query.preload/3](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#preload/3):

```
Repo.all(from p in Post,
           join: c in assoc(p, :comments),
           where: c.published_at > p.updated_at,
           preload: [comments: c])
```

There is also [Ecto.Repo.preload/2](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:preload/2):

```
posts = Repo.all(Post)
Repo.preload(posts, :comments)
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your looking for `preload`.

This example taken from the following blog post by José Valim should get you going:

```
Repo.all from p in Post,
        join: c in assoc(p, :comments),
        where: c.votes > p.votes
        preload: [comments: c]
```

http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/08/working-with-ecto-associations-and-embeds/